# AngularJS controller not accessed

Tags: angularjs

I am learning AngularJS and I have a problem with the controller.

This example below already worked, but it suddenly stoped without any changes that could cause that. I am not sure what is wrong.

The /templates/index.html file does not load.

This is my main index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Todolist</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- ANGULAR JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/todolists.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="app">

<div ui-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my app.js:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

    app.config(function ($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('/', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "app/templates/index.html",
            controller: 'todolists',
        });
});
```

This is my todolists controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app');
var controllers = {};

console.log("test");

controllers.todolists = function ($scope, $http) {

    console.log("test1");

    $http.get('http://localhost:8888/todolist/rest/entries/index.json').
        then(function(response) {

            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.data = response.data;
        });
};

app.controller(controllers);
```

console.log("test") writes to console, but console.log("test1") does not, so the controller is not accessed.

Please take a look and let me know if you have and tips about what could be wrong.

Thanks, Grega

Comment: Is this controller defination valid ? Where did you see that ?

Comment: why is controllers defined as an object?

Comment: A friend who has been working with anguraljs for a while has all his controllers defined like that, so I guess it should be ok to define it like an object. And the way it is also worked before, so I do not thing that is the problem. But if you thing I should change the definition, please write how. Thanks

Comment: a good starting point is the [Angular Seed Project](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed)

Comment: is todolists defined when app.config runs?? what if you move the contents of your function into the state provider so controller: function($scope, $http) {..}  give that a test

Comment: @Tik I tried that but nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a name for the controller is the problem. Ive registered the name 'todolistCtrl' which is the first argument needed for the controller registration method. the second argument is the function controllers.todolists.

you can then reference todolistCtrl within you State Provider.

**controller**

```
var controllers = {};

console.log("test");

controllers.todolists = function ($scope, $http) {

 $http.get('http://localhost:8888/todolist/rest/entries/index.json').
        then(function(response) {

            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.data = response.data;
        });

};

angular.module('app')
.controller('todolistCtrl', controllers.todolists);
```

**app**

```
     var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

    app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('/', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "index.html",
            controller: 'todolistCtrl',
        });
});
```

**Plunker**
[Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/QzPAh5ZzDnkzMvmqMQql?p=preview)